# Modes of convergence for a *continuous-time* stochastic process

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes

I know that if a sequence of non-negative random variables $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ satisifies

$$\mathbb{E}(X_n) \rightarrow 0 $$

as $n \rightarrow \infty$ implies that a subsequence converges almost surely to $0$.

But suppose we have a non-negative process $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ satisfying

$$\mathbb{E}(X_t) \rightarrow 0 $$

as $t \rightarrow \infty$.

What is the strongest thing we can say about almost sure convergence in this case?

(Of course, for instance, you can get a subsequence  $q_{n_k} \uparrow \infty$ of any sequence of rationals $q_n \uparrow \infty$ such that $X_{q_{n_k}} \rightarrow 0$ a.s., but I'd like something stronger....)

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you mean to say $\mathbb{E}(|X_n|) \rightarrow 0$ etc.? Otherwise consider $X=\pm1$ with equal probability

Comment: thanks yes I have made an edit